# How to plot my tibble in r like shown below?

Tags: r

My tibble looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  clusters neuroticism introverty empathic    open unconscious
     <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1        1      0.242       1.02     0.511  0.327      -0.569 
2        2     -0.285      -0.257   -1.36   0.723      -0.994 
3        3      0.904      -0.973    0.317  0.0622     -0.0249
4        4     -0.836       0.366    0.519  0.269       1.00  
5        5      0.0602     -0.493   -1.03  -1.53       -0.168
```

I was wondering how I can plot this with `ggplot2`, so that It looks like the big five personality profiles shown in this picture:

[image]

My goal is to plot an personality profile for each cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot it you'd typically need to have the data in a long format. A `tidyverse`-solution using `pivot_longer` and then `ggplot` could look like:

```r
df |>
  pivot_longer(-clusters) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = name,
             y = value,
             fill = as.factor(clusters))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Data:**

```r
df <-
  tribble(
  ~clusters,~neuroticism,~introverty,~empathic,~open,~unconscious,
  1,0.242,1.02,0.511,0.327,-0.569,
  2,-0.285,-0.257,-1.36,0.723,-0.994,
  3,0.904,-0.973,0.317,0.0622,-0.0249,
  4,-0.836,0.366,0.519,0.269,1.00,
  5,0.0602,-0.493,-1.03,-1.53,-0.168
  )
```